# When representations of a Borel subgroup can be extended to a parabolic subgroup

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Suppose we have a Borel subgroup $B$ of a linear algebraic group and a 1-dimensional representation $\pi:B\rightarrow \mathbb{C}_\lambda$, where $\lambda\in Hom(\mathbb T,\mathbb{C}^*)$ with $\mathbb T$ the maximal torus.

Choose some simple root $\alpha$, consider the minimal parabolic subgroup $P_\alpha$ containing $B$.

My question is when the representation can be extended to a representation of $P_\alpha$.
Will the answer be $\langle\lambda,\alpha^\vee \rangle=0$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Write $P_\alpha = (SL_2) \ltimes ((\ker \alpha) Rad(P_\alpha))$ where $\ker\alpha$ is the subgroup of $T$. The necessity of your condition is about getting the $SL_2$ to act. Once you impose it, then the group to the right of the $\ltimes$ is acting trivially, so the question has reduced to the $SL_2$ case.

This is reasonably elementary structure theory of algebraic groups and I don't consider it a research-level question.

Comment: I agree that the quetion is not research-level.   It's worth comparing the deeper questions about extensions of representations in papers by Cline-Parshall-Scott *Induced modules and extensions of representations,* Invent. Math. 47 (1978), no. 1, 41–51, *Induced modules and extensions of representations  II*, J. London Math. Soc. (2) 20 (1979), no. 3, 403–414, and by H.H. Andersen *Vanishing theorems and induced representations*, J. Algebra 62 (1980), no. 1, 86–100.

Comment: P.S.  Strictly speaking, your semidirect product might be an "almost" semidirect product if the Levi subgroup has derived group $SL_2$ rather than $PGL_2$.   But that has little effect on the situation.

Comment: I *don't* agree that this question would not be research-level. This depends a lot on the background of the OP, and it is not unlikely that he came across this problem during his research in a different context but he does not have the required familiarity with algebraic groups, which is why he asked it on MO. This is a very good reason to use MO, in my humble opinion.

Comment: I agree with Tom De Medts. I'm certainly no expert and my first guess would be $\langle \lambda, \alpha^\vee \rangle \in\mathbb{N}$.